# ¿Cómo introducir datos en un array de subdocumentos con mongoose a través de un formulario?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, angular2-template, angular

Me gustaria saber como introducir datos en un array de subdocumentos en mongodb.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de MEAN Stack con Angular 4.

Tengo el siguiente schema de mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ChallengeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // _id: String,
    name: String,
    category: String,
    subcategory: String,
    level: Number,
    topic: String,
    questions: [{
        questionText: String,
        answer:[{
            answerText: String,
            succesful: Boolean
        }]
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Challenge', ChallengeSchema);
```

Para leer datos desde la bbdd no tengo ningun problema, utilizando el
siguiente codigo:

```
<dl class="list">
    <dt>ID</dt>
    <dd>{{ challenge._id }}</dd>
    <dt>Category</dt>
    <dd>{{ challenge.category }}</dd>
    <dt>Subcategory</dt>
    <dd>{{ challenge.subcategory }}</dd>
    <dt>Topic</dt>
    <dd>{{ challenge.topic }}</dd>
    <dt>Level</dt>
    <dd>{{ challenge.level }}</dd>
  </dl>
  <div class="container" *ngIf="challenge.questions">
    <div class="row col-12" *ngFor="let question of challenge.questions">
     <dl class="list col-12">
       <dt>Question<dt>
          <dd>{{ question.questionText }}</dd>
          <div class="row">
            <dl class="list col-3" *ngFor="let answer of question.answer">
             <dt>Answer</dt>
             <dd>{{ answer.answerText }}</dd>
             <dt>Succesful</dt>
              <dd>{{ answer.succesful }}</dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
      </dl>
```

El problema lo tengo al intentar introducir datos en el array de
subdocumentos tengo el siguiente html

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Add New Challenge</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form (ngSubmit)="saveChallenge()" #challengeForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Challenge Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
[(ngModel)]="challenge.name" name="name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="challenge.category"
name="category" required>
          <option *ngFor="let c of categoryArray">{{ c }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subcategory">Subcategory</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subcategory"
[(ngModel)]="challenge.subcategory" name="subcategory" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="topic">Topic</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="topic"
[(ngModel)]="challenge.topic" name="topic" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="level">Level</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="challenge.level" name="level">
          <option *ngFor="let l of levelArray">{{ l }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let q of questionsA" >
        <label for="questionText">Question</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question"
[(ngModel)]="challenge.questions[q].questionText"
name="questions[q].questionText">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
[disabled]="!challengeForm.form.valid">Save</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el componente de Angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ChallengeService } from '../../services/challenge/challenge.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-challenge-create',
  templateUrl: './challenge-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./challenge-create.component.css']
})
export class ChallengeCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  challenge = {};
  question =  {};
  levelArray: Number [];
  questionsA: Number [];
  categoryArray: String [];

  constructor(private challengeService: ChallengeService, private
router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let x = 1 ; x <= 20; x++) {
      if ( x === 1) {
        this.levelArray = [x];
      }else {
      this.levelArray.push(x);
      }
    }
    this.categoryArray = ['Core', 'Use', 'Build', 'Think'];
    this.questionsA = [1];
  }

  saveChallenge() {
    this.challengeService.saveChallenge(this.challenge).then((result) => {
      const id = result['_id'];
      this.router.navigate(['/challenge-details', id]);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Quiero meter datos en el array de subdocumentos de questions para
pobrar que funciona y luego supongo que sera igual para el de answer